# decimal to fractions

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, means

When being asked how to solve the Arithmetic Means of $8, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2,$ and $2$, I understand that adding these numbers then dividing by $7$ (the amount of numbers) gives me the decimal $4.85714...$ But when being asked to change this number into a fraction, I do not understand where the $\frac{6}{7}$ comes from in the answer of $4\frac{6}{7}$. Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: Add all the numbers together. This gives the numerator. Then 7 is the denominator. I do not think too many of us could look at the decimal equivalent and get a fraction off the top of our head.

Answer (score 3):

Adding $8, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2,$ and $2$ gives you $34$.
Divide that by $7$. (manually, not with a calculator)

you will get a quotient of $4$ and a remainder of $6$

that gives you the answer $4\frac{6}{7}$ = 4.85714...

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see it:

Let $a = 0.\overline{857142}$ (the overline part repeats).

Then $1,000,000a = 857,142.\overline{857142}$, so:

$999,999a = 857,142$, and then:

$a = \dfrac{857,142}{999,999} = \dfrac{95,238}{111,111} = \dfrac{8,658}{10,101}$

$= \dfrac{666}{777} = \dfrac{6}{7}$

Answer (score 1):

> > Arithmetic mean $= \frac{8+7+7+5+3+2+2}{7} = \frac{34}{7}$

**Now, we calculate $\frac{34}{7}$ by using long division and soon we will get a remainder of $6$, the quotient as $4$, and the divisor as $7$ ($x\frac{y}{z}$ ---- $y$ as the remainder, $x$ as the quotient, and $z$ as the divisor). As the result, we will get: $4\frac{6}{7}$**

We can also cross-check this division by converting mixed number to improper fraction: $$4\frac{6}{7} =\frac{(4\times 7)+6}{7} = \frac{28+6}{7}= \frac{34}{7}$$

Comment: You should learn how to use $\rm\LaTeX$ and then use MathJax to write this answer properly, and not as a scanned page.

Comment: okay. I will make sure to use Latex .@AsafKaragila